# Making web workers work with Angular2/Zone.js

Tags: web-worker, angular

I use web workers in my Angular2 application. When I update the model state from callbacks triggered by a worker (`onmessage`), the UI is not getting refreshed.

My understanding is that the process depends on Zone.js monkey-patching all kinds of browser functions to be able to detect updates from things like XHR or timeouts (and state updates from `setTimeout` do work). Is this supposed to include support for web workers? Do I have to explicitly trigger an update somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html) and trigger the update like so:

```
zone.run(() => {
  // the change detection will run after this function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/examples/src/message_broker/index.ts) from the official [examples repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src) shown below:

```
import {
  UIMessageBus,
  UIMessageBusSink,
  UIMessageBusSource
} from "angular2/src/web-workers/ui/application";

var worker = new Worker("loader.js");
var bus = new UIMessageBus(new UIMessageBusSink(worker), new     UIMessageBusSource(worker));
var VALUE = 5;

document.getElementById("send_echo")
    .addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      var val = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("echo_input")).value;
  bus.sink.send({type: "echo", value: val});
});
bus.source.listen((message) => {
  if (message.data.type === "echo_response") {
document.getElementById("echo_result").innerHTML =
    `<span class='response'>${message.data.value}</span>`;
  } else if (message.data.type === "test") {
bus.sink.send({type: "result", value: {id: message.data.id, value: VALUE}});
  } else if (message.data.type == "result") {
document.getElementById("ui_result").innerHTML =
    `<span class='result'>${message.data.value}</span>`;
  } else if (message.data.type == "ready") {
bus.sink.send({type: "init"});
 }
});
```